# How do I calculate limit of Substitutions per personalization block in SendGrid?

Tags: sendgrid

I'm trying to send an email with SendGrid using a transaction template, and see a problem with substitution limited.

> Substitutions are limited to 10000 bytes per personalization block.

[SendGrid Docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/substitution_tags.html)

I will resolved this problem by get the template from SendGrid and replace all placeholders inside it. But I need to check when I can do it, I think will check limited of substitutions and I don't know How SendGrid calculate it? maybe length of all string in substitutions?

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem and share the solution for the people who care ;)

Solution:

> You need to optimize Substitutions by using it together with Sections

```
    /**
     * When you have the $variables too big, SendGrid will reject the message because
     * SendGrid's Substitution is limited(10000 bytes)
     *
     * Before that, the format of substitution as below:
     *
     * {
     *    "to": [
     *       "example@example.com"
     *    ],
     *    "sub": {
     *       "%FirstName%": "This string maybe too long",
     *       "%LastName%": "This string maybe too long",
     *       ....
     *       ....
     *       more and limited
     *    }
     * }
     *
     * To resolved this problem we will use the Section with Substitution as below:
     *
     * {
     *    "to": [
     *       "example@example.com"
     *    ],
     *    "sub": {
     *       "%FirstName%": "%FirstName%",
     *       "%LastName%": "%LastName%",
     *       ....
     *       ....
     *       more and more
     *    },
     *    "section": {
     *       "%FirstName%": "This string maybe too long",
     *       "%LastName%": "This string maybe too long",
     *       ....
     *       ....
     *     }
     * }
     *
     * We will optimize the strings in Substitutions and let Section in SendGrid to contain that strings.
     */
```

Answer (score 0):

As per sendgrid documentation they are going to remove support for ***Section***. As they says Substitution is alternative for Section. Do you have any other alternative for large content (> 10000 bytes).

Comment: This was published as an answer, but does not attempt to answer the question. Possibly it should be a comment

Comment: Yes but i do not have enough reputations to comment on existing answer, so i thought to post it as answer. If it is not allowed and there is some better way then i can delete this as answer.

Comment: @Bhautik they were recommended this one https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-transactional-templates/, please refer https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/retired-mail-settings/